# Error 500 ApiError or 502 BadGateway: SSL Elasticsearch Traefik Docker - secure elastic with ssl

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, ssl, traefik

i try do secure elasticsearch with traefik but getting the error 502 or 500 depending on the configuration. Other services I successfuly secured with traefik.
Any suggestion would be awesome!

Errors form Traefik logs:

```
Error: 500 Internal Server Error' caused by: tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not 172.16.4.136"
Error: '502 Bad Gateway' caused by: EOF"
```

Every sercie are deployed on the same server.
Compose file for elasticsearch:

```
version: "3.8"

volumes:
 certs:
   driver: local
 esdata01:
   driver: local
 kibanadata:
   driver: local
 metricbeatdata01:
   driver: local
 filebeatdata01:
   driver: local
 logstashdata01:
   driver: local
 fleetserverdata:
   driver: local


networks:
  elastic:
    driver: {{network_type}}
    external: false
  {{traefik_network_name}}:
    external: true

services:
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    networks:
      - elastic
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: es01\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - es01\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          "      - 172.16.4.0/24\n"\
          "  - name: kibana\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - kibana\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          "      - 172.16.4.0/24\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://es01:{{elastic_port}} | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://es01:{{elastic_port}}/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/es01/es01.crt ]"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120

  es01:
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - '{{ dir }}/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
    ports:
      - ${ES_PORT}:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
      - {{traefik_network_name}}
    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network={{ traefik_network_name }}
      - traefik.constraint-label={{ traefik_network_name }}
      - traefik.http.routers.elastic.rule=Host(`{{elastic_app_name}}.{{app_domain_name}}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.elastic.entrypoints=web, websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.elastic.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.elastic.tls.certresolver={{traefik_mode}}
      - traefik.http.services.elastic.loadbalancer.server.port=9200
      ################
      # http 500 and without this file 502 bad gateway
      - traefik.http.services.elastic.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https
      # https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-secure-elastic-cluster-with-docker-traefik-ssl/289933/3
      # suggestion to add this, but no progress:
      - traefik.http.serversTransports.elastic.insecureSkipVerify=true
      # https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-secure-elastic-cluster-with-docker-traefik-ssl/289933
      # also no progress with this:
      # - traefik.tcp.routers.elastic.tls.passthrough=true
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      # https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-secure-elastic-cluster-with-docker-traefik-ssl/289933/2
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/es01/es01.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/es01/es01.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1500m -Xmx1500m"
      ######## https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-secure-elastic-cluster-with-docker-traefik-ssl/289933/3
      # - xpack.security.authc.api_key.enabled=true
    mem_limit: ${ES_MEM_LIMIT} #dont work at swarm
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
    restart: unless-stopped

  kibana:
    depends_on:
      es01:
        condition: service_healthy
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - certs:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - kibanadata:/usr/share/kibana/data
    networks:
      - elastic
      - {{traefik_network_name}}
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    labels:
      # works fine
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network={{ traefik_network_name }}
      - traefik.constraint-label={{ traefik_network_name }}
      - traefik.http.routers.kibana-http.rule=Host(`{{kibana_app_name}}.{{app_domain_name}}`)
      - traefik.http.routers.kibana-http.entrypoints=web, websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.kibana-http.tls=true
      - traefik.http.routers.kibana-http.tls.certresolver={{traefik_mode}}
      - traefik.http.services.kibana.loadbalancer.server.port=5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://es01:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - XPACK_REPORTING_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - server.publicBaseUrl={{kibana_app_name}}.{{app_domain_name}}
    mem_limit: ${KB_MEM_LIMIT}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
    restart: unless-stopped
```

.env file for elasticsearch:

```
ELASTIC_PASSWORD = {{elastic_password}}
KIBANA_PASSWORD = {{kibana_password}}
STACK_VERSION=8.11.3 
CLUSTER_NAME=docker-cluster
LICENSE=basic
ES_PORT={{elastic_port}}
KIBANA_PORT={{kibana_port}}
ES_MEM_LIMIT=5073741824
KB_MEM_LIMIT=1573741824
LS_MEM_LIMIT=1573741824
ENCRYPTION_KEY={{elastic_key}}
```

Traefik config:

```
global:
  checkNewVersion: false
  sendAnonymousUsage: false
log:
  level: DEBUG
  format: common
  filePath: /var/log/traefik/traefik.log

accesslog:
  format: common
  filePath: /var/log/traefik/access.log
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: :80
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: websecure
          scheme: https
  websecure:
    address: :443
certificatesResolvers:
  staging:
    acme:
      email: accounts@ecocheck.app
      storage: /acme.json
      caServer: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web
  production:
    acme:
      email: accounts@ecocheck.app
      storage: /acme.json
      caServer: "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: web

providers:
  docker:
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    directory: /etc/traefik
    watch: true
```

I try to access elastic search with python. When I'm using the IP its working perfectly. When i try to use the url it is not woring:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
NODES_IP = [
    'https://123.123.123.123:9200/',
]
NODES = [
    'https://myurl.com'
]
def get_client(nodes):
    return Elasticsearch(
            hosts=nodes,
            basic_auth=("user", "pw"),
            verify_certs=False,
            node_selector_class="random"
        )
        
query = {
    "index": 'someindex.someindex',
    "query": {"match": {
        "code": {
            "query": "3243567"
        }
    }}
}

#### with IP its working
ip = get_client(NODES_IP)
result_ip = ip.search(body=query)
print('result', result_ip)
ip.close()

#### with URL its not working
url = get_client(NODES)
result = url.search(body=query)
print('result', result)
url.close()
```

Comment: Does `elasticsearch-certutil` really support network masks (like your `/24`)? I would have never seen that anywhere before and the error message also points in that direction

Comment: I don't know. I tried it with and without.

Comment: Did you add the right IP? `172.16.4.136` needs to be in that list (if you want to specify it based on IP). Though unless you assign specific IPs, which you probably don't want / need, use the DNS name instead when referencing the container (`es01` in your example). Not sure how that works with Traefik unfortunately.

Comment: The IP of the service changes after every restart, so i hoped to find a way without a static IP. Nevertheless i set a fixed IP for one try, but i dot not worked. Haven't i set the es01 in the right spot in the config or do i missunderstand something?

Comment: But you are trying to access it through the name `es01` and not the IP any more? That should at least change the error message, right?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot answer your question. I added the python I used to test it.

Comment: And that is still the same error message "certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not 172.16.4.136" as in the beginning?

Comment: Yes, it does...
it theme to be an uncommon error in this constellation.